# word.exe has stopped working using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

when I remove return in else section the code throw word.exe has stopped working
I tried to debug and when the base condition is true and 'i' start to decrement when 'i' is equal to 1 it throws the error

```
string o = "555";
string play(int i){
    if(i == 3) return o;
    else
        return play(i+1);
}
```

Comment: Why would Word crash because of this code? What *is* this code? What's the purpose of it? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If the return type is not `void`, reaching the final `}` rather than a `return` causes undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including "stopped working".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude FWIW I think Word.exe is the name of this program.

Comment: yes word.exe the name of the program

Comment: This seems to be a common newbie misunderstanding related to recursion. If `play` was called from itself (possibly several times), `return` doesn't return all the way back to the code that called `play` for the first time. You need to `return` from each invocation of `play` separately.

Comment: You can't remove the return. It's undefined behavior to do so. Every call of play() must return a string.

Comment: BTW if you call `xyz = play(4)` with the code as it stands in the question, you'll be in trouble as well as the base condition (`i == 3`)  will never be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove the `return` statement.

Indeed, `play()` returns a `string`. So if the condition is `true`, you return the `string` `o`. But if you enter the else block, you also have to return a `string`, because the `play(i+1)` will return a string if its condition succeed, but nothing otherwise (except running another call). And you don't want to get nothing, you want to get back the resulting `string`.

In other words, when the child function returns a `string`, **the current function needs to pass it to its parent and so on**. If the child function condition succeeds and you missed the return statement, you will never pass this result to the parent and finally, you will return nothing at the top (Unexpected behaviour or error, honestly I didn't try).

---

And by the way, the code you are running is very dangerous. If the `int` passed in parameter is greater than `3`, the recursion will run endlessly, adding `play()` calls until running out of memory.

I hope it answers your question :)